Automatic fan rotation switching CW/CCW
I'm refurbishing an old electric oven which has a convection fan, I would like to invert the rotation of the fan every few minutes to better distribute hot air around the oven, currently I'm using a SPDT switch but using a manual timer and doing the switching manually and that's gets boring quickly.
I would like to make the CE/CCW switching automatically with a preprogrammed interval; is there any type of "switch"that does this?

Why do you think that reversing the fan will improve the heat distribution? Have you tried measuring the temperature in different parts of the oven at the same time and found significant differences? The air paths in the oven have probably been designed for unidirectional flow, transferring the heat uniformly from the elements to the interior. Reversing the flow may well cause hot spots where air does not flow backwards properly.

I have never seen such a product but someone may design one given adequate motivation..

Interesting -- a reversible fan? Usually, they're small, non-reversible shaded-pole AC motors. What sort of fan motor does that oven use? Was it intended to reverse?? And why would reversing it help? It would seem likely to fight against the natural convective airflow!

use a microcontroller and a couple of relay? That's the most obvious solution though

The original controller alternates fan rotation but it is toast and I'm trying to find a solution; the fan is capable of reversing rotation and it definitely had improved results as hotspots have been reduced.
